# Randomly generated password Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, passwords

For the purpose of a new web app, I would need on my sign up page (which is administrator only) just only one email field.

The thing is that I'm totally new at rails and so even basics things like that are for me really difficult...

I created my authentification using Railscast #270 which uses **has_secure_password** method.
For now, everything works great except that I dont need all this bullcrap...
I also want to use Action Mailer to send the generated password to his email adress.
A hex(8) password would be perfect (I have seen **SecureRandom** but it seems to be depreciated)

Users_Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :is_connected?, :only => [:new, :create]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Tell the Mailer to send a welcome Email after save
      Mailer.confirm_email(@user).deliver

      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

User_model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
  has_secure_password
  validates_presence_of :password, :email, :on => :create
end
```

For now, in my view, I have 2 fields. But as I said earlier, I only want one.
I would like to keep using has_secure_password which seems to offer a pretty good security regarding hash/salt.

Comment: Is your question "how do I set the password for my user and email it to them?"

Comment: Basicly i want to write something that would generate a password and set it into a variable in order to be accessible from my mailer view and witch will be stored in my db as password_manifest. I have no idea how to do those things.

Comment: OK, so i did what Frederick said.
Worked great but is there a way to do it without passing @random = SecureRandom.hex(8) to the view ?
Because i didnt know what to do so i passed it to my view as a hidden_field, then i reuse it in my create methode...
So its controller > view > controller for nothing -_-

Comment: In the create method of the controller, set the password and then pass it to the user and then to the user_mailer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Rails provides `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` which either (depending on the Ruby version) is just a bridge to Ruby's `SecureRandom` or reimplemented it on older versions of Ruby (if my memory is correct `SecureRandom` was added in 1.8.7)

Now that all of the versions of Ruby that Rails supports have `SecureRandom` built-in `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` is no longer needed and has been deprecated. `SecureRandom` itself is going nowhere -

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.hex(8)
```

should do fine (you might want to consider `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` for a more compact representation of the same amount of actual randomness)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one simple code for random password with lenth 8

```
rand_password=('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(8).join
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I used `rand_password = (('0'..'9').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a).shuffle.first(8).join` to get only alpha numeric signs without special chars

Comment: Shouldn't you be using secure random number generation for passwords?

Comment: The trouble with this is I always get the same result 'GCjE2psB'

Comment: I would not recommend using this one liner because:
- Same character is not used in the result.
- Maximum length of result is 75 even if I specify large number like 100.
- `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(10)` is more secure and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things from Rails are deprecated because they duplicate functionality that has been added to Ruby core, and [SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) seems to be one of those things.

You can use any of those random generator methods to produce a one-time-use password.

Answer (score 1):

To Create `Random` and `unique` token/password

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :generate_password

  def generate_password
    self.password = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      # If you are using FFaker gem then you can use it otherwise
      # SecureRandom is great choice
      # random_token = FFaker::Internet.password
      break random_token unless User.exists?(password: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

The main object here is to generate random token and do not repeat that token in the database. It can be really useful for some cases like generating `unique token`, `unique invoice number`, etc