# assign random password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I currently have in my application the ability for a user to create an account with a username and password and then have an email sent to them.

In order to generate a more secure log in, I wish for a random password to be generated and then in the email sent to the user the password is contained there.

I am just wondering how I would do this. I have a password_hash and salt in my database so it would require having the random string assigned there.

I understand that I would have to have in my model something like

```
 before_save :assign_password
```

and then a

```
def assign_password
     stuff
end
```

Is this all I would need and it would assign to the `password` field? what would I include in the `def assign_password?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomly generated password Rails 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066245/randomly-generated-password-rails-3-1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def assign_password
  (0..6).map{ ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join
end
```

Source [How to generate a random string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)

Comment: Don't use this! This doesn't use secure random number generation.